# Script for showing/hiding on click - how can I write this code cleaner?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this simple code, but it's messy - how do I do it cleaner?

It works like this: If you click on the `menu-btn1` the `div` shows up, and hide others, but if you click on `menu-btn1` again it will hide as well.

```js
let coll = document.getElementsByClassName('collection');
let dis = document.getElementsByClassName('display');
let drop = document.getElementsByClassName('drop');

document.getElementById("menu-btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(coll[0].style.display == 'none') {
    coll[0].style.display = 'block';
    dis[0].style.display = 'none';
    drop[0].style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    coll[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <span id="text"><span id="menu-btn1">collection</span></span>
</div>

<div class="collection" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="display" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="drop style="display:none;"></div>
```

There is nothing important in css really, only the grid positioning.

Comment: Your code seems won't work: 1. Your last element (drop) has wrong quote marks. 2. Last 2 elements (display and drop) are always `display: none` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

First I think that using `document.querySelector` seems much user friendly than using `document.getElementsByClassName`. Instead of `let coll = document.getElementsByClassName('collection'); coll[0].xxx`, we can just use `document.querySeletor('collection').xxx`.

So code can refactor a bit to

```
    let coll = document.querySelector('.collection');
    let dis = document.querySelector('.display');
    let drop = document.querySelector('.drop');

    document.getElementById("menu-btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
        if(coll.style.display == 'none') {
            coll.style.display = 'block';
            dis.style.display = 'none';
            drop.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            coll.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
```

Next, I will place the DOM retrieval code into the event handler, to prevent unnecessary namespace pollution. Though maybe in your working code, you may use the `coll` for other handling, then it is okay to place there. In addition, I don't think one will change the variable of a DOM to other value, so I would use a `constant` instead.

```
    document.getElementById("menu-btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
        const coll = document.querySelector('.collection');
        const dis = document.querySelector('.display');
        const drop = document.querySelector('.drop');
        if(coll.style.display == 'none') {
            coll.style.display = 'block';
            dis.style.display = 'none';
            drop.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            coll.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
```

> However these changes does not resolve the fact that `display: none` is actually scattered in both HTML and Javascript. I think a better idea is just to place the code in one place. That is remove the styling in HTML.

To do so, I think there are possibly 2 approaches, one is the use of `RxJS`, another way is to use of data driven approach, e.g. `React`, `Angular`, `Vue`, ...

#### Data Driven Approach: Use of VueJS

Let's first have a look at How we can implement it in Data Driven Approach.
I will use Vue for demonstration, as it is the simplest to setup among the three.

```js
new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            template: `
            <div class="ui">
                <div class="menu">
                    <span id="text"><span @click="show = !show">collection</span></span>
                </div>

                <div class="collection" :style="styles">
                    Collection Inside
                </div>
            </div>
            `,
            data: function() {
                return {
                    show: false
                }
            },
            computed: {
                styles: function() {
                    return {
                        "display": this.show ? "block": "none"
                    };
                },
            },
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  </div>
```

As you can see, the HTML code is now placed in Javascript as a template, and we make use of `:style` and `@click` in the template, instead of normal HTML. These are Vue specific
syntax and is used in Vue for easy interaction between the Vue component Javascript and the template.

#### Event Driven Approach: RxJS

Another approach would be RxJS, that just work without a framework, so makes it more easy to adopt in a legacy web application.

```js
rxjs.merge(
    rxjs.of(1), // so that it immediately triggers
    rxjs.fromEvent(document.querySelector("#menu-btn1"), 'click'),
)
    .pipe(
        rxjs.operators.scan((accum, value, index) => {
            return index % 2 == 1;
        }, false)
    ).subscribe(show => {
        const coll = document.querySelector(".collection");
        const value = show ? "block" : "none";
        coll.style.display = value;
    }

    )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <span id="text"><span id="menu-btn1">collection</span></span>
</div>

<div class="collection">
    Collection Inside
</div>
```

Here is all the solution I think of, and it is left to you to decide which way is the cleanest code. To me, I just like the way `RxJS` is constructed, and do not need to maintain an extra data for storage.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things that You could improve:

- Why do You treat a `span` element as a button when there is a more semantic solution which is a `button` element
- Another bad practice is an inline styling. It gives too much `specificity` to the element and it's hard to maintain that. Use stylesheets instead.
- Your variable names should be more descriptive. You want to make Your code reading experience as easy as it's possible so that other devs can easily understand it.
- Instead adding css styles using JS. Add a `css class` using JS and create those rules in the stylesheet.
- If I understand what You want to achieve correctly, Your code mechanics could be replaced using the `event delegation` pattern